# calculate rolling count of new records in python

Tags: python, count, rolling-computation

i'm unsure this is possible, but let me expose the problem

example data :

```
        date  users
     0  2012-09-29  A
     1  2012-09-29  B      
     2  2012-09-30  A     
     3  2012-09-30  C     
     4  2012-10-01  B      
     5  2012-10-01  C
```

i want to calculate the number of new users each day , but just compared to the day before.
meaning for example that user B who visited the 29/9 but not the 30/9 will count as a new user on the 1/10

with a result looking like this in this case

```
        date  users
     1  2012-09-30  1         
     2  2012-10-01  1
```

thank you so much

Comment: Be more specific as to what to tried, where you are stuck, what data you have (list, csv, ...)!

Comment: create a set of users for each day. Then count the users that are not member of the set of the previous day. The initial previous day set is of course empty. If you don't have users every day, you'll need to detect missing days from the list

Answer (score 1):

You could do a repeated `set` and track the size:

```
prev_users = set("AB")
for crnt_users in whatever:
    value = len(set(crnt_users) - prev_users)  # this is your value
    prev_users = crnt_users
```